# Dirt bike wont start after making pop noise

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

Went out riding with my old, (but new to me) ttr 250 2003. This bike was in terrible condition then got rebuilt some years later and hadnt been ridden since it was rebuilt 2 years ago. It had been ridden last few weeks now and then. Bought it off a mate in working terrific comdition its basically a new bike. only been hour and a half of riding and because to me its a new bike ive stalled it a couple times throughout the session. When we got further out into the bush i was disoriented as to where i was and stalled it from low revs. But when i stalled it, it made a pop noise like i stepped on a chip packet without the crinkling.....obviously. and since then i havnt been able to start it again. I tried the electric start but instead of that turning over sound plus electric sound its just a electric wirring sound. Like something is spinning without being connected to that which makes the bike turn over. Ive roll tried roll starting which just locks up the back wheel wont work at all. And the kick start which only makes that bob noise. Wont even get a few just one dead sound. Wont turn over or anything. 
I am aware of one problem the bike has prior to this. It would burn a lot of oil and it was smokey as hell from the exhaust. I think this may be loose piston ring seals or something. (I dont know much about mechanics at all just throwing out possibilities) ive been told starter motor, timing chain, pistons, spark plug even. Can anyone help and give us a solution to this? Anything would he much appreciated. 
Might be delay on me getting back to anyone who does reply.
Also, i am new to this group/page/support chat. Whatever it may be i am new, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the spark plug is still installed? If it wasn't torqued properly it might have unscrewed and just happened to come out at that time. It makes a pop sound similar to what you describe, and then when you try to start it you can hear the air whooshing out of the cylinder. If this is the case, be sure not to tighten it too much in your zeal to prevent future failure, or you'll strip the cylinder head.

Comment: Its not the park plug. Thats fine. Even got a new one just to be sure. Ive checked top end and that's all fine aswell. I think its the starter motor because the wirring noise is coming from the starter motor and nothing is happening. I dont know if im using correct terminology but where the starter cog is it turns and it wont turn the magneto cog. Or its spinning but the actual part of the cog that turns the motor over, its like those two parts are not connected and working together. Im quite sure this is where i problem is and i am not sure what to do. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: hmmmm....   that does make sense about the electric starter,  but then that wouldn't prevent you from push-starting it.  Have you confirmed that it really can't push-start?

Comment: I took the bike out earlier today after reading your reply. I gave it another shot and at this time the electric starter was still buzzing and the starter motor was just spinning. I took it onto the road where good grip is and i gave it my best shot at trying to start it. After awhile it actually started trying to start. I ran it hard and jumped on and it started breifly. Then konked out. And since then the startermotor has been working. I use electric start and it actually turns the bike over but it wont start. As if there is no spark. New spark plug to.now the starter motor is working..what?